# Connecting multiple Action methods to one View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The problem I am facing is that when the delete link is clicked and my delete actionResult is called it errors out saying there is no view for delete. I have tried setting ActionName("Index") but then I get an ambiguous error message regarding the View Index.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ***code goes here****

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
        [OnAction(ButtonName = "Create")]
        public ActionResult Index(***code goes here***)
        {

            ***code goes here****


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //GET:
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            ***code goes here****

            return View(lansing);
        }

        //POST:
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
        [OnAction(ButtonName = "Delete")]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            ***code goes here****

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I then have one table that gets updated with information that the user puts in as well as delete information when an actionLink is clicked from the table which is handled by both of these ActionResults.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which view to render by passing the name of the view as first argument to the call of the `view` method (see the documentation of [ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd470748%28v%3dvs.100%29) or [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).

But as the `HTTP GET Delete` method usually is used to show the user the elements to delete and prompt the user to confirm the deletion (see this [ASP.NET Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/details?view=aspnetcore-2.2)), you maybe want to add a dedicated view for it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem I was facing was to actually perform the the actions of the Delete Post inside of the Get Delete method, because of using one view for both Creation, Editing, and Deleting.

The end result looked like this:

```
  public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            ***code goes here****

           var lansing = db.LansingMileages.Find(id);
            viewModel.Records = new[]
            {
                lansing
            };

            db.LansingMileages.Remove(lansing);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```